# Toolbar options are disabled in BaseX

Tags: xml, editor, xquery, basex

I am using BaseX 9.7.2 and I don't know why most of my toolbar options are disabled so I can't use them except for the "New","Open & Manage", "Editor", "Result" and "Info".
Even when I go to the "Visualization" Menu all the choices there are disabled.
I downloaded the software today so it's up to date.
Can someone help me or have any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution :
I was opening my XML files directly left-bar navigator instead of opening it from the "Open & Manage" options on the tool-bar and create a database for it.